# Cannot replace html.tpl.php with new template in a single module

Tags: 7, theming, routes

I am creating a module to handle the reformatting of pages for printing in D7.

The structure of the URL is: `/print/{nid}`

I need to use a separate template than html.tpl.php as I have to get rid of our global header/footer but I still need our javascript and css to load.

I'm at a loss for how to correctly implement this.

I have created a menu_hook, otherwise I get a 404 page

I have tried using the `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__print';` but I get no output

```
<?php
// print.module
function print_menu()
{
    $items  = array();

    $items['print/%node']   = array(
        'title' => '',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'page callback' => 'print_process_print',
    );

    return $items;
}

function print_process_print(&$vars)
{
    error_log(__FUNCTION__.' called');
    error_log('node: '.var_export($vars, true));

    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][]  = 'html__print';

}
```

My template file is: `sites/all/themes/zen/templates/html--print.tpl.php`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A page callback isn't the same thing as a theme preprocess function, what you're doing can't work...read through [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430), it should help

Answer (score 0):

To create your own template override in a module is not the same as doing it in a theme. Look at [Overriding a template file (.tpl.php) from a module](http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/overriding-template-file).

Put this code in your module, and put the template file in a sub-directory 'templates'. Clear the cache.

```
function MODULE_preprocess_html(&$vars){
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][]  = 'html__print';
}

function MODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE') . '/templates';
  $templates = drupal_find_theme_templates($theme_registry, '.tpl.php', $path);
  foreach($templates as &$template) {
    $template['type'] = 'module';
    $template['theme path'] = path_to_theme();
  }
  $theme_registry += $templates;
}
```